# What Google app engine Auth to use to only expose my "intranet" site only to my GSuite users?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am pretty new Google app engine, and though I have hacked around with alot of languages, I am finding the google documentation a little overwhelming.  I have successfully launched a static site, and successfully run some python code from the console. But I have not run any python from my static site.

I am a Small company trying to setup a google app engine static/dynamic website that I only want to expose to my Gsuite users.

I have some python code I want to run on my app engine, which will download a file from gdrive/teamdrive, process the file, create a new file from the results and then upload the resulting file to the same folder.

I may also at a later date have this static/dynamic website also interfacing with Cloud SQL(mysql) or an external database.

my Questions

1. What authentication method to use to only expose this website to my gsuite users?
2. Though I have worked through some of the GDrive api examples whats the best and easiest method of passing GDrive text files to my python code?  (though I have hacked around with python lots in the past, the html and python combination perplexes me)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [OAuth2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) to acquire a token which you can then use to interact with that user's files through the GDrive API (see "[About Authorization](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)" as well as [this quickstart Python example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)).

Comment: Awesome thanks!!!  This has me going in the right direction!  How do I prevent unauthorised people from accessing this app and static website?  I only want it accessible to my GSuite users.  I realise the user can authorise the app, but I would want to prevent external users from accessing my database as well.

Comment: @Trevor You can use [the `hd` parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param) but you should also [validate the returned `hd` claim](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#validatinganidtoken) and error if it doesn't match your domain.